# Can't find variable: QK_middlewareReadModePageDetect at global code

Tags: ios, iphone, safari

Only on iPhone iOS 15.3 on 'Mobile Safari UI/WKWebView 15.3' viewing an asp.net v4.8 webapp with jQuery UI - v1.10.4 - 2014-01-17

Any suggestions on origin, or how to mitigate?